# Run first and last 3 days of the every month

Tags: cron

How to run a job on the first and last 3 days of the month. What's the cron (linux) syntax to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to indicate the last days, rather than checking which ones.

These are the days to check:

```
29, 30, 31 - months with 31 days --> 1,3,5,7,8,10,12
28, 29, 30 - months with 30 days --> 4,6,9,11
26, 27, 28 - February --> 2
```

First 3 days of the month:

```
0 0 1,2,3 * 0
```

Last 3 days of month:

```
* * 26,27,28         2       *  # February
* * 28,29,30     4,6,9,11    *  # 30 days months
* * 29,30,31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 *  # 31 days months
```

Comment: And how about leap-year? :)

Comment: @Aleksandrs that is not possible, since cron does not allow year :/ You should probably run some condition together with `date`.

Comment: But for example if I am using this: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: @Aleksandrs yep, you can make it work with that one.

Comment: Actually I didn't found way how to do "last 3 days every month" with Quartz library with 1 cron expression, only 1 day with "L"

Comment: @Aleksandrs I would split it in two expressions and say Y/4 27, 28, 29 and the rest would have 26, 27, 28.

Comment: I just noticed, why did you write 5 expressions for "Last 3 days of month", if its possible to do 3 like you described in your first block of code?

Comment: @Aleksandrs you are right! I made it this way to make it easier to track, but it is indeed more cumbersome. Edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First 3 days of month**

Cron expression :- **0 0 0 1-3 * ?**

Description :- At 00:00:00am, every day between 1st and 3rd, every month

**Last 3 days of month**

Cron expression :- **0 0 0 L-3 * ?**

Description :- At 00:00:00am, 3 days before the end of the month, every month

Comment: This is the tight answer for Spring cron 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

This cron config worked well for me, thanks to Crontab Guru's easy to understand interface. https://crontab.guru/#0_8_1-6,28-31_*_*

```
0 8 1-3,28-31 * *
```

Run every day at 8am from 1st to the 3rd and 28th to 31st. '-' represents range.

Answer (score 0):

I use this formula:

```
# first 3 days of month    
0 0 1-3 * * echo "match"

# last 3 days of month    
0 0 * * * [[ "$(date -d '+1 days' +\%d)" == "01" || "$(date -d '+2 days' +\%d)" == "01" || "$(date -d '+3 days' +\%d)" == "01" ]] && echo "match"

# first and last 3 days of month in one command line:
0 0 * * * [[ "$(date +\%d)" == "01" || "$(date +\%d)" == "02" || "$(date +\%d)" == "03" || "$(date -d '+1 days' +\%d)" == "01" || "$(date -d '+2 days' +\%d)" == "01" || "$(date -d '+3 days' +\%d)" == "01" ]] && echo "match"
```